Sum of alternating binomial coefficients that is evaluated on a finite subset of positive integers
Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $I\subset\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$.
For simplicity, I define
$$S_n(I) := \sum_{i \in I}(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}.$$
For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, it is well-known that $S_n(\{0,1,\dots,n\})=0$. But, I am interested in the following problem:
Find every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that there exists $I\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}$ that fulfills
$S_n(I)=0.$
Notice that I only consider $I\subset\mathbb{N}$ here.
In other words, I exclude $0$.
With this modification, only some values $n$ can fulfill the condition.
For instance, it is easy to check that for $n=4$, there is no $I\subseteq\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $S_n(I)=0.$
On the other hand, every odd $n$ fulfills the condition trivially, since for any $i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, we have $S_n(\{i,n-i\})=0$.
I also notice that for $n=6k+2$,  as we have
$$\binom{6k+2}{2k+1}=2\binom{6k+2}{2k}=\binom{6k+2}{2k}+\binom{6k+2}{4k+2}$$
which implies for $I=\{2k,2k+1,4k+2\}$, we get $$S_{6k+2}(I) = \binom{6k+2}{2k} -\binom{6k+2}{2k+1} +\binom{6k+2}{4k+2} = 0.$$
Initially, I thought that for every $n=6k$ with $k\in\mathbb{N}$ (and also for $n=6k+4$ with $k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$), there is no $I\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}$ with $S_n(I)=0$.
So, I posted this problem.
But, @HackR found out that for $n=24$, we can take $I_1=\{3,4,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,20\}$. Then, $S_{24}(I_1)=0$.
So, I did a complete search using Magma programming for every $n=6k$ and $n=6k+4$ up to $n=30$ (I put the code in the comment just in case it is needed).
Up to $n=30$, I confirmed that $S_{24}(I_1)=0$ and the only $n$ with that property is $n=24$. I also found that we can also take $I_2=\{2,5,6,7,9,10,11,14,18,22\}$.
Then, $S_{24}(I_2)=0$ too.
update: I also found out that for $n=34$, for instance, we can pick $I=\{13,14,15,20\}$. Then, $S_{34}(I)=0$.
So, specifically, I want to ask the following question:
For $n=6k$ (where $k\in\mathbb{N}$) and $n=6k+4$ (where $k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$), can we characterize every $n$ with property: there exists $I\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $S_n(I)=0$?

Magma code: Asum := func< n,c | &+[(-1)^i c[i]Binomial(n,i) : i in [1..n/2]] >;
S := func< n |[ Append(c,i) : c in CartesianPower({0,1,2},IntegerRing()!(n/2
-1)), i in [0,1] ] >;
IsAny := func< n | [ c : c in S(n) | Asum(n,c) eq 0]>;
SS := [6k : k in [1..4]] cat [6k+4 : k in [0..4]];
[ n : n in SS | #IsAny(n) gt 1];
